# Blur UIImage async in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, asynchronous, xamarin.ios, uiimage, blur

I want to blur an image asynchronously in Xamarin.iOS, but when I try, I get an exception telling me I cannot do this outside the main thread (it calls `EnsureUIThread`).

I have tried 2 ways of doing this: [`FXBlurView`](https://github.com/nicklockwood/FXBlurView) and [`ImageEffects`](https://gist.github.com/p1nt0z/960aca0aeb390690ad9d), but they both don't allow asynchronous blurring.

How can I make the blurring happen asynchronously?

Answer (score 0):

There's a simple answer, separate the blurring and the actual creation of the `UIImage`. The blurring can happen on an other thread or async, and the actual usage of the image should happen on the UI thread.